# std::atomic to what extent?

Tags: c++, c++11

In the C++ Seasoning video by Sean Parent https://youtu.be/W2tWOdzgXHA at 33:41 when starting to talk about “no raw synchronization primitives”, he brings an example to show that with raw synchronization primitives we will get it wrong. The example is a bad copy on write class:

```
template <typename T>
class bad_cow {
    struct object_t {
        explicit object_t(const T& x) : data_m(x) { ++count_m; }
        atomic<int> count_m;
        T data_m;
    };
    object_t* object_m;

public:
    explicit bad_cow(const T& x) : object_m(new object_t(x)) { }
    ~bad_cow() { if (0 == --object_m->count_m) delete object_m; }
    bad_cow(const bad_cow& x) : object_m(x.object_m) { ++object_m->count_m; }

    bad_cow& operator=(const T& x) {
        if (object_m->count_m == 1) {
            // label #2
            object_m->data_m = x; 
        } else {
            object_t* tmp = new object_t(x);
            --object_m->count_m; // bug #1
            // this solves bug #1:
            // if (0 == --object_m->count_m) delete object_m;
            object_m = tmp;
        }
        return *this;
    }
};
```

He then asks the audience to find the bug, which is the bug #1 as he confirms.

But a more obvious bug I guess, is when some thread is about to proceed to execute a line of code that I have denoted with label #2, while all of a sudden, some other thread just destroys the object and the destructor is called, which deletes `object_m`. So, the first thread will encounter a deleted memory location.

Am I right? I don’t seem so!

Comment: Is it just me or does `count_m` have an **undefined value** when `object_t` is constructed.  The constructor for `std::atomic<int>` does not initialize the underlying value to zero - at least not on VS2017 or VS2019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your objection doesn't hold because `*this` at that moment is pointing to the object and the count is 1. The counter cannot get to 0 unless someone is not playing this game correctly (but in that case anything can happen anyway).

Another similar objection could be that while you're assigning to `*this` and the code being executed is inside the #2 branch another thread makes a copy of `*this`; even if this second thread is just reading the pointed object may see it mutating suddenly because of the assignment. The problem in this case is that `count` was 1 when entering the `if` in the thread doing the mutation but increased immediately after.

This is also however a bad objection because this code handles concurrency to the pointed-to object (like for example `std::shared_ptr` does) but you are not allowed to mutate and read a single instance of `bad_cow` class from different threads. In other words a single instance of `bad_cow` cannot be used from multiple threads if some of them are writers without adding synchronization. Distinct instances of `bad_cow` pointing to the same storage are instead safe to be used from different threads (after the fix #1, of course).

Answer (score 3):

> some other thread just destroys the object and the destructor is
>   called, which deletes object_m. So, the first thread will encounter a
>   deleted memory location.
>
> Am I right? I don’t seem so!

Assuming the rest of the program isn't buggy, that shouldn't happen, because each thread should have its own reference-count object referencing the `data_m` object.  Therefore, if thread B has a `bad_cow` object that references the data-object, then thread A cannot (or at least should not) ever delete that object, because the `count_m` field can never drop to zero as long as there remains at least one reference-count object pointing to it.

Of course, a buggy program might encounter the race condition you suggest -- for example, a thread might be holding only a raw pointer to the data-object, rather than a `bad_cow` that increments its reference count; or a buggy thread might call `delete` on the object explicitly rather than relying on the `bad_cow` class to handle deletion properly.